# Button вложенный в ListView, как заставить его реагировать?

Tags: c#, wpf

В XAML есть создание кнопки (вместе с другими элементами):

```
<GridViewColumn Width="30">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="15" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0">
            +
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Как созданную кнопку заставить реагировать на какие-либо события?

Помимо кнопки есть еще поля продукции, класс:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Placement { get; set; }
    public int NumPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Для которого отдельно создается коллекция:

```
List<Product> products;
```

Затем в коллекцию добавляется элемент:

```
products.Add(new Product { Title = "Adobe Photoshop", Number = 1, NumPrice = 10, Price = 20, Placement = "в наличии (скидка 50%)" });
LW.Items.Refresh();
```

А вместе с элементом добавляется кнопка.

Вопрос в том как заставить кнопку влиять на значения?

Допустим кнопка "+" увеличивает количество Number в Adobe Photoshop (данные в примере).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой `ItemsControl` (коим является и `ListView`) устанавливает своим элементам `DataContext`, воспользуйтесь этим. Подпишитесь на событие клика по кнопке и:

```
var product = (sender as Button).DataContext as Product;
product.Number++;
```

Comment: А если у меня две кнопки? "+" и "-" не могу почему-то подстроить код.

Comment: @Виктор, для каждой кнопки свой обработчик сделайте

Comment: Я это и пытаюсь сделать, но, не понимаю как (кодом).

Comment: Не могу перехватить эту кнопку (её создание).

Comment: Вам не нужно делать это кодом, добавьте в разметке обработчик: `Click="Button_Click"`

Comment: Так кнопок будет много, каждый раз добавляя продукт добавляется кнопка с "+" и "-", при этом каждая должна отнимать и прибавлять только к той строке, в которой она появилась.

Comment: Или мне нужно создать Button_Click и перехватывать то место в котором была нажата кнопка?

Comment: Попробуйте уже наконец сделать то что я вам написал. Кнопок будет много, хоть у всех и будет один и тот же обработчик, у них будет разный `DataContext`, по которому мы определим нужный `Product`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68935/discussion-between--and-).